# iOS 11 accessoryDidConnect and accessoryDidDisconnect notification more then 5 time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In iOS 11 beta, my app stops working because of accessoryDidConnect & accessoryDidDisconnect notification called multiple time(5 times) and finally, stop with accessoryDidDisconnect. Here is my code works fine in ios 10.3.3 earlier version. Please help me is there any changes made in iOS-11 related to EAAccessoryManager. Checked full updates for iOS-11 but apple did not mention anywhere,

Thanks for the support.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accessoryDidConnect:) name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accessoryDidDisconnect:) name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
     [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
```

Added UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols also

Comment: Are the `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self:... name:EAAccessory...Notification` called only once?

Comment: It's calling alternatively 5 times, didconnect and did disconnect

Comment: Please read full question, its iOS-11 beta not working (it works fine in iOS-10 and previous version). and I am using MFi licensed Lightning and 30-pin connector

Comment: I read it. But first, iOS 11 is a Beta version (also, is it the last one?), which means not exempt of issues, and it also may have provides a change that makes your `addObserver:` to be called more than 1 times. We could for instance imagine a non-well release object that is calling multiple times `addObserver:` since you didn't say where you put that code.

Comment: I added this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions(AppDelegate).